# Rxjs seams to not be able to find some of its members

Tags: angular, npm, rxjs

Everything was working in my project when I accidentally messed up something in my node_modules.  Everything got messed up I managed to fix everything I think exept I am getting a failed compilation on `ng serve` which is throwing the error:

```
ERROR in ../../node_modules/@angular/common/src/location/location.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/vladimir/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'SubscriptionLike'.
../../node_modules/rxjs-compat/Observable.d.ts(1,22): error TS2305: Module '"/home/vladimir/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'Subscribable'.
../../node_modules/rxjs-compat/Observable.d.ts(1,36): error TS2305: Module '"/home/vladimir/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'SubscribableOrPromise'.
../../node_modules/rxjs-compat/Observable.d.ts(1,59): error TS2305: Module '"/home/vladimir/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'ObservableInput'.
../../node_modules/rxjs-compat/add/observable/of.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/vladimir/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has noexported member 'of'.
../../node_modules/rxjs-compat/add/observable/timer.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/vladimir/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' hasno exported member 'timer'.
../../node_modules/rxjs-compat/operator/switchMap.d.ts(1,22): error TS2305: Module '"/home/vladimir/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'ObservableInput'.
../../node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(21,5): error TS2416: Property 'lift' in type 'Subject<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Observable<T>'.
  Type '<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
    Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.
```

I tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling I also tried

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latestnd
```

I get the same error.   My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "dynamic-data",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "json-server": "cd ./google_analitics && python ./simpleserver.py",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
      "typescript": "^2.4.2",
      "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
      "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
      "@types/gapi": "0.0.35",
      "@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.47",
      "angular2-draggable": "^1.4.2",
      "core-js": "^2.5.4",
      "jsforce": "^1.8.4",
      "json-server": "^0.14.0",
      "leaflet": "^1.3.1",
      "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
      "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
      "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
      "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
      "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
      "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
      "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
      "agm-overlays": "^1.1.3",
      "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
      "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
      "karma": "~1.7.1",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
      "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
      "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
      "protractor": "~5.3.0",
      "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
      "tslint": "~5.9.1",
      "typescript": "~2.7.2"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.7",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.11",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.7"
  }
}
```

This error almost seams like there is a version mismatch on something but I can't figure out what.  Is that correct?  Thx

Comment: Try run npm install

Comment: I have tried that @KamilNaja

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Comment: I am using angular6 so should this be npm cache verify or use --force @KamilNaja ?

Comment: this is not working with either --force or verify that seams to me this means there is something wrong with package.json

Comment: Indeed I did try sudo

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf node_modules/ 
npm cache verify --force 
npm install @angular/cli@latest -g 
npm install @angular/cli@latest 
npm install